# unable to load certificate 6300:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, private-key

When I run the command below to check my private-key PEM file, an error pops up

`unable to load certificate 6300:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE`

`command : C:\>openssl x509 -in C:\private-key.pem -text -noout`

any idea?

Answer (score 4):

This happens mostly when your key is password-protected.

Firstly you have to decrypt it:

```
$ openssl rsa -in protected.key -out unprotected.key
```

Then you have to recreate your .pem file again:

```
$ cat unprotected.key yourcert.crt > yourcert.pem
```

After that you can issue all the commands you need. If you encounter any troubles trying stuff above, check your key and cert files for line endings (openssl does not like Windows ones) and BOM-mark.

Answer (score 3):

You are testing the private key and not the x509 certificate. Therefore `openssl rsa` (assuming it is rsa key) is to be used as in:

```
$ openssl rsa -in testkp.pem -text
```

This would print something like the following:

```
Private-Key: (2048 bit)
modulus:
....
publicExponent:
privateExponent:
...
prime1:
...
prime2:
....
exponent1:
...
exponent2:
....
coefficient:
.....
writing RSA key
..
....
```

Comment: error again **C:\>openssl rsa -in C:\private-key.pem -text**
unable to load Private Key
10744:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:.\crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1327:

10744:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:.\crypto\asn1\tasn_de
c.c:381:Type=X509_ALGOR
10744:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:.\crypto\asn1\
tasn_dec.c:751:Field=pkeyalg, Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
10744:error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:ASN1 lib:.\crypto\pem\pem_pkey.c:132:

Comment: when you open the pem file, what is the first line: does it say something akin to "RSA private key"

Comment: How does it end as "END RSA PRIVATE KEY"? There is only one entry in that file, correct?

Comment: yes..this is how it ends "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

Comment: One last try: -sgckey option. See if that helps.

Comment: also I am assuming that your file has only one entry which is the PK.

Comment: You saved my day!